# Need help regarding Chrome extension dev

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to pass a url on the current tab from contentScript to background and display it in console. But I am alaways getting one error :

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["scripting", "activeTab"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

Here is my contentScript.js

```
// contentScript.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.type === "executeScript") {
    var script = new Script(message.script);
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }
});
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  type: "printToConsole",
  message: "Hello from the content script!",
});

function getActiveTab() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "getActiveTabRequest" });
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.type === "getActiveTabRequest") {
    const activeTab = message.activeTab;
    console.log("Active tab URL:", activeTab.url);
  }
});

getActiveTab();
```

Here is my background.js

```
// background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.type === "executeScript") {
    var script = new Script(message.script);
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: sender.tab.id },
      func: script,
    });
  }
});
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.type === "printToConsole") {
    console.log(message.message);
  }
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.type === "sendData") {
    const data = message.data;
    console.log("Received data from content script:", data);
    // Process the data here
  }
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.type === "getActiveTabRequest") {
    (async () => {
      const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true,
      });
      const activeTab = tabs[0];
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        type: "getActiveTabRequest",
        activeTab: activeTab,
      });
    })();
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Much appreciated!!

Comment: 1) Some tabs aren't allowed to run content scripts (e.g. newtab or chrome:// or other extensions). 2) You need to [re-inject content scripts](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension. 3) It's unclear why you use a content script at all as you can do it directly in the background script by subscribing to chrome.tabs.onActivated + chrome.tabs.onUpdated + chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.

Comment: Apart from what @wOxxOm mentioned, you don't need to add a new listener for every message type in the background script: you can use one listener for all messages.

Comment: The program can't read what you want to do, so it can't create an example for you.